# Azure IAAS, PaaS and SaaS services products list

Tags: azure

Does Azure provide any URL to fetch the list of IAAS, PaaS and SaaS services products provided by Azure

This URL https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/ gives me the list of all products but I'm not able to distinguish between SAAS, IAAS and PAAS service products, Hence a filter will be good to know which product belongs to which service

Kindly share me a URL where I can apply filters for services Or anything related

Comment: SO is for programming questions, and asking any kind of URLs is also off-topic.

Comment: @JamesZ Ok, can u provide me any REST APIs to fetch the list of SaaS, PaaS and IaaS services used by  Azure.

Comment: Why would there even be such API? And if there would, once again, off-topic.